# A proof of quadratic variation of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

In Stochastic Calculus for finance by Shreve, there is a theorem claim that (pg. 156, Theorem 3.44)

---

$$\langle B\rangle(T)=T,$$
or more precisely,
$$\mathbb{P}\lbrace \omega \in \Omega:\langle B(.,\omega)\rangle(T)=T\rbrace=1.$$

---

But his proof only proves that the random variable
$$Q_{\prod}-T=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[(B(t_{k+1})-B(t_{k}))^2-(t_{k+1}-t_{k})],$$
where $$\prod=\lbrace t_0,...,t_n\rbrace$$ is a partition of $[0,T]$, which
has the properties
$$\mathbb{E}(Q_{\prod}-T)=0$$
and
$$Var(Q_{\prod}-T) \to 0$$
as the size of $\prod$ tends to zero.

I believe that the proof only proves
$$Q_{\prod}-T \to 0 \mbox{ in }L^2$$
and $L^2$-convergence doesn't imply the almost sure convergence, am I right? If this proof is not complete, then what is the missing part?

Comment: I don't have access to that book but you can get a complete proof of almost sure convergence from the following link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwiU3uaqw9rdAhUPAXIKHaqjCwcQFjAEegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.unl.edu%2F~sdunbar1%2FMathematicalFinance%2FLessons%2FBrownianMotion%2FQuadraticVariation%2Fquadraticvariation.pdf&usg=AOvVaw10tFxaFDnO0_-Fl9syN8Ur

Comment: So the conclusion is correct but the proof is not complete.

Comment: Right, I don't think almost sure convergence follows so easily.